# discord bot to randomly generate a quote

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot for discord that gives a random response.

Here is my current code:

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
 if (msg.content === 'ping') {
  var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

  if (roll == 1) msg.reply('pong');
 } else {
  msg.reply('prong');
 }
});
```

How would I modify it so it gives three random responses?

Comment: that works great thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
const array = ['first message', 'second message', 'poggers message'];
message.channel.send(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]);
```

---

`console` example:

```js
function getRandomResponse() {
  const array = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'how was your day?', 'ping', 'pong', 'test'];
  console.log(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]);
};
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getRandomResponse()" class=button>Reroll Response</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple 8ball command.

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    const arguments = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const commandName = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) && commandName == "8ball") {
        var facts = [`Yes`, `No`, `Maybe`];
var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
message.channel.send(facts[fact]);
    }
})
```

Hope this works!